# How to change the color of the Numeric characters in a Textview

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uitextview, ios5

i am using this code in `- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`to separate the text fom the numbers in a a textview.my code of that is

```
//removing string in text

NSString *originalString = myStringTxt;
NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
                                   stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
                           characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", strippedString); // "123123123"
```

stippeString contains numeric charters from the group of text,,i just want to change the font color of these numeric characters .i know multiple colors are not possible in UITextView,but is there anything possible hack method or something which can change the color of the above string?.Please help me to do this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can *not* have multiple colors in a `UITextView` object.  Only one color is possible.

But there are potential alternatives you can use.  One that I know about is JTextView, the [source code for which is available here](http://github.com/jeremytregunna/JTextView).  There are probably other alternatives that you can look up here on StackOverflow or via Google. The important thing is that they need to handle "`NSAttributedString`" objects (which is how one can assign font styles to ranges within a string).

I suspect this is one of these oft-requested things that Apple is going to fix in a forthcoming iOS version (e.g. iOS 6), but we won't know about it until it's announced.

Comment: ,i know this is not opossible with UITextview,but we have the strippedString contains numbers,so can we modify the stripped string to change its color using a color drawing using core graphics or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass UITextview and change the `layerClass` method to return `CATextLayer`. You can now use NSAttributedString to the string property of `CustomTextView.Layer`.

- Cast customTextView.layer as CATextLayer
- You can have multiple colors in NSAttributedString

Comment: ,haii, but i can't use core text for this purpose,becz i need it editable

Answer (score 0):

Core text may help you color texts or you can use uiwebview.

exmple at this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text)

Comment: haii,but i can't use core text,becz i need to the text editable

Comment: than you can customize uiwebview. seems only solution to me. post solution please if you can figure out

Comment: ,bess sure,i can't do it in web view,becz of the limitations in the webvieww